# Compute dot product of two vectors without using extra libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to write a function to compute the dot product of two vectors without using extra libraries. Following is an attempt that I made. Can someone point out the flaws in my code?

```
def dot(vector01,vector02):
    result= []
    for i in range(len(vector01), len(vector02)):
        total = 0
        total += vector01[i] * vector02[i] 
        result.append(total)
    return result
    if len(vector01) == len(vector02):
        return result
    else:
        print(error)
vector01 = [2, 3, 4]
vector02 = [4, 2, 1]
print(dot(vector01,vector02))
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I'm looking for some pointers as to why my code isn't working as is. Is it in the wrong order or format? The correct answer should be 18

Comment: It seems from your attempt that you don't currently have a very strong grasp on python. I would recommend going through a basic tutorial, such as [this one](https://www.learnpython.org/)

Answer (score 1):

```
def dot(v1,v2):
    if len(v1) != len(v2):
        raise ValueError
    return sum(i1*i2 for i1,i2 in zip(v1,v2))
```

Comment: thank you for your solution i've obtained this solution, but I am trying to write a solution that sticks to for loops and if statements with out using the built in python functions.

Comment: I wanna know how not to use built in python functions. Since, `+-*/`,`len()`,`range()` also is "**built in**" function in python.

Comment: by built in functions I mean sum and zip sorry for not saying that earlier.

Comment: the only two I'm keeping myself to using is len() and range()